# Завершение работы ASP.NET приложения

Tags: asp.net, c#

Почему, когда моё приложение удаляет папку с файлами, web-приложение завершает свою работу?

Comment: Код в студию! Какую папку? Какое приложение?

Comment: просто в c# directory.delete(dir, true).
при отладке после этого выполняется код из процедуры Appication_End в файле global.asax

приложение: asp.net 3.5 web-application.

Comment: Просто так приложение не должно завершаться. Так что информации для ответа недостаточно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   /|\
  / | \
    |
    |
```

@Fiztex
"Просто так приложение не должно завершаться. Так что информации для ответа недостаточно."

**достаточно**

Нужно отключить мониторинг файлов в IIS.

```
        PropertyInfo p = typeof(HttpRuntime).GetProperty("FileChangesMonitor", 
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

        object o = p.GetValue(null, null);

        FieldInfo f = o.GetType().GetField("_dirMonSubdirs", 
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);

        object monitor = f.GetValue(o);

        MethodInfo m = monitor.GetType().GetMethod("StopMonitoring", 
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        m.Invoke(monitor, new object[] { });
```